# Angular : show length of array of objects on HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to show length of an array on the HTML page, but it is displaying nothing. I am not even getting any errors in console. Please guide how to get the total number of heros.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros">
 <div>number of heros are {{hero.length}}</div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
"heros":[
{
"name":"batman",
"id":"A1001"
},
{
"name":"superman",
"id":"A1002"
},
{
"name":"spiderman",
"id":"A1003"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `heros.length` and you do not need an `ngFor`

```
 <div>number of heros are {{heros.length}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the array is of 'heros' and not 'hero'.
Another thing is that you should move it out of the *ngfor scope, in this scope there's a hero object that you can bind to the name and id properties.